# Optional object parameter in typescript

Tags: typescript

I am creating a simple function with an object parameter. It accepts `openDialog` boolean property which decides whether to run another function. I am not defining an interface for it because it is ever going to be a single property. My issue is how do I define it in such a way that I am no longer required to pass an empty object to that function? `openDialog` is optional so what is the right syntax for making that object optional too?

```
function renderComponent({ openDialog }: { openDialog?: boolean }) {
  render(
    <Component />
  );

  if (openDialog) clickButton('Import Existing');
}
```

Typescript complains about `renderComponent()` with

> Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.

It accepts `renderComponent({})`

I am aware of a default parameter `function renderComponent({ openDialog }: { openDialog?: boolean } = {}) {` but I am wondering whether there is a different way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are trying to achieve.

```
function renderComponent(openDialog? : { openDialog?: boolean }) {
    render(
        <Component />
    );

    if (openDialog) clickButton('Import Existing');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since destructuring a possibly undefined object does not work:

```
function renderComponent(args?: { openDialog?: boolean }) { 
    // not possible, since type of args is { openDialog?: boolean } | undefined
    const { openDialog } = args;
}
```

I ended up using a default initialization `args = {}`:

```
function renderComponent(args: { openDialog?: boolean } = {}) { 
    // destructuring works now, since type of args is { openDialog?: boolean } | {}
    const { openDialog } = args;
    // you can use openDialog now, which ofc may be undefined if not provided
}

// can be called even without passing an empty object
renderComponent();
```

Notice, that you don't need the `?` after `args` if you provide a default value.

Answer (score 1):

That error:

> Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.

means that you must pass (one) object as an argument to this function.

If you would't pass `openDialog` parameter with this code you should
call this function like this:

```
renderComponent({});
```

If you would have optional argument you should do like this:

```
function renderComponent(args? : { openDialog?: boolean }) { 
    // your code 
}

renderComponent();
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert `={}` after `{ openDialog }: { openDialog?: boolean }` but inside the parameter parentheses.
Completely, it looks like this:

```
function renderComponent({ openDialog }: { openDialog?: boolean } = {} ) {
    render(
      <Component />
    );
  
    if (openDialog) clickButton('Import Existing');
  }
```